# javascript method to delete content from recycle bin of a single site only

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, javascript, client-object-model

So I know you can use jvascript:emptyItems() in the address bar of the recycle bin to clear it, but this clears the entire site collection.

Is there a way using javascript to empty the recycle bin for only a single site? Current sites context, or specifying the site?

the reason I am asking for javascript particularly is that I need a front end solution to this, something like javascript in SPD is the extent of development capabilities.

Thanks as always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JS Client Object Model there is class by which you can access the recycle bin of the site collection but not a specific web. However, you can iterate through the items in the recycle bin to determine whether to delete or keep them. Have a look at it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff411858

Answer (score 2):

did you tried [spweb.recyclebin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.recyclebin.aspx) yet

or

[SPWeb.recycle](http://www.novolocus.com/2012/03/30/missingmethodexception-when-calling-spweb-recycle-in-sandbox-solution/)

Hope it helped, if it doesn't help then what exactly code you used before ?

Comment: sorry if I was unclear; update question I need a front end solution. the most i can use is javascript/jquery in SPD or text files in CEWP kinda thing. I have to make this available to other end users in a generic kind of way.

Comment: thanks though. something knew to learn :)